# CSS Why is :not() not working without specifying the tag type?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```css
* {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.day {
  color: gray;
}

.today {
  color: blue;
}

:not(.today) .date {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<span class="day">Tuesday<span class="date"> • 4</span></span>
<br>
<span class="day today">Wednesday<span class="date"> • 5</span></span>
```

I would expect the  `• 5` part to be blue because of `:not(.today) .date` but it renders as orange:

[image]

If I add `span` before `:not`, then it works fine. But why do I need to add it?

If I add a `*` before `:not`, then it remains orange.

Is there a way to have it blue without having to specify `span`?

Comment: html and body are `:not(.today)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to have it blue without having to specify `span`?

Yes, restrict the selection to elements with the `day` class:

```css
.day:not(.today) .date
```

```css
* {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.day {
  color: gray;
}

.today {
  color: blue;
}

.day:not(.today) .date {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<span class="day">Tuesday<span class="date"> • 4</span></span>
<br>
<span class="day today">Wednesday<span class="date"> • 5</span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alter  `:not(.today) .date` -> `:not(.today) > .date`

```css
* {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.day {
  color: gray;
}

.today {
  color: blue;
}

:not(.today) > .date {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<span class="day">Tuesday<span class="date"> • 4</span></span>
<br>
<span class="day today">Wednesday<span class="date"> • 5</span></span>
```